# Extract a Word from String Containing a Specific Character within Substring

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, text-extraction

In MS Excel I would like to use a formula to extract only the word from a cell that contains a specific character ("=") within the text.

A2:  Dolly made me a homemade=cake and some muffins

A3:  we had cheese=cake for dinner

A4:  Everyone loves how the bakery makes some awesome=cakes

A5:  Johnny made his own dinner=lastnight and then cleaned the kitchen

A6:  There was a tremendous amount of raing State=Oklahoma

I would like the following from in column (A2:A4) to provide the following results in column (B2:B4).

B2:  homemade=cake

B3:  cheese=cake

B4:  awesome=cakes

B5:  dinner=lastnight

B6:  State=Oklahoma

I've attempted several approaches, some closer than other, but not able to figure it out, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an old text parsing trick that greatly increases the distance between the words with repeating zeroes through the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) and [REPT functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04C4D778-E712-43B4-9C15-D656582BB061) which affords a larger swipe of the intended substring.

[image: Parse Substring with SUBSTITUTE and REPT]

The formula in B2 is,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), MAX(1, FIND("=", SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99)))-50), 99))
```

The [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) (used as a wrapper) removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: can you please tell me the significance of `99` and `50` in this formula. Sorry but I couldn't understand.

Comment: The `SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99))` turns every single space in the sentence into 99 spaces so the words are *very* spread apart. After locating the **=** sign, we go back 50 characters (which should put us into the middle of one of the 99 space separations and then collect everything for the next 99 characters. You're left with <lots of spaces><what you want><lots of spaces>. The TRIM gets rid of the unwanted leading/trailing spaces. If the substring to be retrieved was larger, just replace with 999 and 500.

Comment: Clever idea. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I used 5 helper columns to do this; they could be collapsed into one very long forumula, but I prefer it this way (easier to track down source of any errors I think). Given the strings you have in A2; In B2 this finds location of "="

```
=SEARCH("=",A2)
```

In C2 this finds the instance number of the " " preceeding the "="

```
=B2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,1,B2)," ",""))
```

In D2 this notes the location of that " "

```
=SEARCH(CHAR(33),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(33),C2))
```

In E2 this locates the " " trailing the "=", or if the "=" appears in the final word in the cell it notes the full cell length +1

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",A2,B2),LEN(A2)+1)
```

Using these values in F2 this pulls the string from the preceeding " " to the trailing " "

```
=MID(A2,D2+1,E2-D2-1)
```

Comment: Michael thanks it worked perfectly - : ) Both answers provided works, but a shorter array of formula's and the use of only one cell column works best in this instance.