# Extract text one word to the right of delimited value within string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract, delimiter

I've tried numerous formulas and cannot seem to figure it out using the RIGHT, LEFT and MID functions. Using MS Excel, I would like to extract only one word (two spaces) to the right of my delimiter value `^`.

EXAMPLE: Cell A2

> Johnny and I were planning on going to the movie to see ^Batman Returns, but it was to late.

Results: Cell B2

> ^Batman Returns,

Comment: see [Extract a Word from String Containing a Specific Character within Substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632814/extract-a-word-from-string-containing-a-specific-character-within-substring/32646134#32646134).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("^",A2),FIND("¦",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("^",A2),99)," ","¦",2)))
```

Just change the '2' at the end to adjust your capture of spaces to the right of the delimiter.

Comment: Hi and Thanks All, I have tried each of forumulas and all worked phenomenally in capturing the data to the right of the delimited value.  Lastly, can the exact same be done, using the same principals but to the LEFT of the delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Expand the spaces with the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) and [REPT functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04C4D778-E712-43B4-9C15-D656582BB061) then chop out a piece with [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-2EBA57BE-0C05-4BDC-BF81-5ECF4421EB8A) and finally clean it up with the [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9).

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), FIND("^", SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99))), 199))
```

[image: Substring from String at special character]

Comment: JEEPED!!! AWESOME...  It worked, I would like to know is there a way to make increase or interchange the space range.  For example, I want to capture text 3 or 4 spaces over to the right of the delimiter?

Comment: If the **199** collects two words based on a **99** space expansion then changing 199 to **399** will probably retrieve four words. Note that because the length of each word is not constant, sooner or later you may run into problems that 99 spaces is not enough to reliably retrieve 10 words with **999**. In that case, change all of the 99's to 999's and the 199 to **1999**.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, the following formula it works:

```
MID(A1;FIND("^";A1);FIND(" ";A1;FIND(" ";A1;FIND("^";A1))+1)-FIND("^";A1))
```

A1 is the cell where you have your text that will be checked to extract the piece you are interested.

The formula looks for the index of ^ character

`FIND("^";A1)`

then look for the index of the second space from that ^ character index

```
FIND(" ";A1;FIND(" ";A1;FIND("^";A1))+1)
```

use this second index to subtract the first index to get the piece of text length from ^ character until the second space after that

```
       second index            first index
FIND(" ";A1;FIND("^";A1))+1) - FIND("^";A1)
```

AND finally use the MID formula to retrieve the piece of text desirable.