# How to Extract number from text?

Tags: excel

```
740-742 Burwood Highway
465-467 Payneham Road
217-221 Glen Osmond Road
45-47 Darlinghurst Rd
```

How can I extract number only with DASH (-) for example: 375-377 using Excel formula?

Comment: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2738-excel-extract-text-before-after-dash.html

Comment: See also [Extract a Word from String Containing a Specific Character within Substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632814/extract-a-word-from-string-containing-a-specific-character-within-substring/32646134#32646134)

Comment: It is not solution I need. It only find specific character . How can i get Numbers with character ,.

Comment: @SewakTamang This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with formulas/codes you are trying to develop.  Post what you have tried and indicate where you have run into problems.  If all your data is as you show, then just combine `LEFT` and `FIND` to extract everything up to the first space.  If not, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)